# Unable to connect with opc server using VS 2012 + c# + opc server kepware

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, opc

I am writing to enquire about a problem with the kepware server. I am using the `version kepware V4.180.338` with the following features:

```
     Operating system: Window 7 
        Visual studio version: Microsoft visual studio ultimate 2012 (licensed).
        Net framework: Version 4.5
```

I use the c# in order to design a client application which connect with the OPC server and read/write  items.

I always have a problem with this instruction

```html
    server.Connect(url, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
```

> The error is "Could not load file or assembly 'OpcRcw.Dx,
>   Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable"

I use the dll `“OpcNetApi.Com.dll, OPCHDA.dll, OpcNetApi.dll and opcdaauto.dll”`. I tried to change the configuration of the project to `x86` also to change the folder of all dll but always there is the same bug.

Have you any idea about this problem please? Is the version of kepware  not compliant to the platform?

Comment: *The specified file is not found* Where's the `OpcRcw.Dx` file?

Comment: I add these dll also OpcRcw.Comn.dll/ OpcRcw.Da.dll/ OpcRcw.Dx.dll in bin/debug folder also i added these dll in bin/x86/debug folder and i have the same problem

Comment: where can i find OpcRcw.ae.dll please?

Comment: It used to be available from https://opcfoundation.org. Did you had a look there already? You will need to register first.

Answer (score 0):

I use the version V5 of the kepware server and the problem is resolved.